# play framework storing whole console output to log file

Tags: file, logging, console, playframework-2.2

I would like to have all output from my play application to be stored in log file. 
To print information to console I use System.out.println() command;
Please give me some hints how to configure play.

For now play is storing only something like this:

```
2014-01-23 15:15:53,134 - [INFO] - from play in main 
database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:/baza.sql

2014-01-23 15:15:54,591 - [INFO] - from play in main 
Application started (Prod)
```

Any help will be aprecieate.
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application level logging using scala:

```
import play.api.Logger._    
logger.info("Hooray! I am logging things")
```

Application level logging using java:

```
import play.Logger;
Logger.info("Hooray! I am logging things in java")
```

Additionally, Play uses [logback](http://logback.qos.ch) as its logging engine. So as far as logging configuration goes, you have available to you the full power of logback. Have a look at the excellent Play [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger) on the subject.